# Difference between int* and int[] in C++

Tags: c++

Context: C++
Consider the example below

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    int A[];
    int *B;

public:
    TestClass();
};

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    A = 0; // Fails due to error: incompatible types in assignment of `int' to `int[0u]'
    B = 0; // Passes
}
```

A = 0 fails but B = 0 succeeds. What's the catch? What exactly is A? A constant pointer? How do I initialize it then?

Comment: Consider using an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) or a [`boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/array.html) instead.

Comment: Hey thanks but I'm just interested to know what's going on internally

Comment: See my answer, and the error that Comeau shows!

Comment: yeah .. guess it's a bug in g++. It chewed my head for a while.

Comment: it's not a bug in g++; after all it gives error if you compile it with `-pedantic` option. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference between them is that `int A[]` *in a class* would not compile, and should not compile!

## Comeau C++ compiler gives this error:

> ```
> "ComeauTest.c", line 4: error:   
> incomplete type is not allowed   
>       int A[];
>           ^
> ```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeau_C/C%2B%2B) says,

> **Comeau C/C++ has been regarded as the
> most standards-conformant C++
> compiler.**

**I therefore would suggest : Don't write such code even if your compiler compiles it.**

Comment: :) cool ! I am using g++. Ok so I guess this is a bogus declaration.

Comment: @EFreak : Are you using any options? Compile it as  `g++ -pedantic filename.cpp` .. and tell me the result. I'm curious :-)

Comment: test.cpp:5: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array `A'. Thank you very much !

Comment: @EFreak: I was expecting that error. Thanks for confirming. :-)

Answer (score 19):

The question "what is the difference between int* and int[]?" is a less trivial question than most people will think of: it depends on where it is used.

In a declaration, like `extern int a[];` it means that somewhere there is an array called `a`, for which the size is unknown here. In a definition with aggregate initialization, like `int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` it means an array of a size I, as programmer, don't want to calculate and you, compiler, have to interpret from the initialization. In a definition without initialization, it is an error, as you cannot define an array of an unknown size. In a function declaration (and/or) definition, it is exactly equivalent to `int*`, the language specifies that when processing the types of the arguments for functions, arrays are converted into pointers to the contained type.

In your particular case, as declaration of members of a class, `int a[];` is an error, as you are declaring a member of an incomplete type. If you add a size there, as in `int a[10]` then it becomes the declaration of an array of type `int` and size 10, and that will reserve space for 10 `int` inside each object of the class. While on the other hand, `int *b` will  only reserve space for a pointer to integers in the class.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is an array, and in C++ you need to specify the array size when you define the variable itself i.e. you need to do something like `int A[10]`. Then you can access individual elements using `A[0], A[1]` etc. `B` is a pointer, so doing `B=0;` sets the pointer to NULL. If you don't want to specify the size at compile time, but still want array like syntax you can use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Thanks Asha! But if I don't do that. How does the compiler interpret it is my question. If itr allows a declaration then probably it should also allow a definition to exist. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`int A[]` is an memory range inside the class instance, where `int *B` is a pointer that you may or may not initialize later.

so

`A=0` means that you want to change a pointer that cannot be changed,

where

`B=0` means that you are changing a pointer to point to 0x00000000

Comment: What is a memory range? If C++ allows empty declarations like this, there also should be a way to initialize that I guess. (Just for curiosity)

Comment: I guess that falls into the area 'not all possible things in c++ are really useful'

Answer (score 1):

A[] is an array with its size undefined. You need to declare it like this:

int A[SIZE];

then initialize it like this:

A[0] = 0,
A[1] = 5,

etc

Answer (score 1):

The code snapshot you have there should not compile since `A[]` is effectively a zero sized array, thus an incomplete type, which is not allowed in class specifications.
For e.g. Visual Studio fails to compile this with these errors:

> 1>...\test.h(4) : warning C4200:
>   nonstandard extension used :
>   zero-sized array in struct/union 1>
>   Cannot generate copy-ctor or
>   copy-assignment operator when UDT
>   contains a zero-sized array
>   1>...\test.h(5) : error C2229: class
>   'TestClass' has an illegal zero-sized
>   array

To initialize and use `A[]` you must declare it as static and initialize it with file scope like this:

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    static int A[];
    int *B;

public:
    TestClass();
};

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    //A = 0;  Yes this is wrong, see below.
    B = 0; // Passes
}

int TestClass::A[] = {1,2,3};
```

As for A = 0 this is wrong too and Visual Studio will complain with this error, which is self explanatory:

> 1>..\test.h(13) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int []'
>     1>        There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays.

LE: Also see [David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851234/difference-between-int-and-int-in-c/4851462#4851462) answer for a complete interpretation of zero sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

long answer short, A is of type array
and B is of type pointer to int.

A[] initializes an array of zero size, which you cannot assign a value to.

Btw, you can ask C++ yourself with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class TestClass{
  private:
    int A[];
    int* B;
  public:
    TestClass();
};

TestClass::TestClass(){
  cout<<"Type A: "<<typeid(A).name()<<endl;
  cout<<"Type B: "<<typeid(B).name()<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  TestClass A;

  return 0;
}
```