# Array initialization [c/c++]

Tags: c++, c

Why this is not allowed?

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Foo {
int fooId;
char arr[ ];
} fooList[] =
{ {1, {'a', 'b'}},
  {2, {'c', 'd'}}
};

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    printf("%d %c\n", fooList[i].fooId, fooList[i].arr[0]);
}
```

whereas, this is allowed:

```
struct Foo {
int fooId;
char arr[2]; // this line modified
} fooList[] =
{ {1, {'a', 'b'}},
  {2, {'c', 'd'}}
};
```

Comment: C and C++ are different here.  Which one are you interested in?

Comment: this is just for learning, so how they are different here will be interesting to know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only the *last* member of a C struct can be flexible as in `arr[]`.

Shamelessly copying from paragraph 6.7.2.1, sub-paragraph 16 of the ISO C99 standard:

> 16 As a special case, the last element
>   of a structure with more than one
>   named member may    have an incomplete
>   array type; this is called a flexible
>   array member. With two    exceptions,
>   the flexible array member is ignored.
>   First, the size of the structure shall
>   be    equal to the offset of the last
>   element of an otherwise identical
>   structure that replaces the  flexible
>   array member with an array of
>   unspecified length.106)...

EDIT:

As for C++, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412749/507519). Bottom-line: flexible array members are not allowed in C++ at all - at least for the time being.

Comment: Thanks, the comment was before I could see your edited text ;)

Comment: I think it's wrong in C++? In c you can malloc memory of any size and put there your struct, while in C++ new  will always allocate sizeof(struct) memory.

Comment: @thkala: It is simply not allowed.  You can hack around it in a similar way as C89 allows (which isn't surprising given that C++98 is based on C89), but this addition to C99 is just not valid C++ and hasn't been incorporated into C++0x.

Comment: @Fred: I assume you mean getting by with a `[1]` array and allocating additional memory. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Nice find on the linked question.

Comment: @Fred Nurk, it has not been and will never be incorporated into the language. The issue there is the same as with variable length arrays, they would break the type system. Currently the size of the array is part of the type, and is known at compile time, if that is replaced, then these particular types of arrays would not be usable for compile time constructs (consider `template <typename T, int size> int size_array( T (&)[ size ] ) { return size; }`. As always it could be stated in the standard, but that would create a second different "array" citizen.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Did I say otherwise?

Comment: @Fred Nurk, no, I just wanted to add to your answer (it is not allowed, will not be in the upcoming standard) that it is not that the issue was not discussed, but that a decision was taken not to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ all members of an user defined type must have complete types, and the member `arr` does not have a complete type unless you give it a size.

In C, the struct definition would compile, but you might not get what you want. The problem is that an array without size is allowed at the end of a struct to be used as a proxy to access the contiguous block of memory after the instance. This allows a dumb vector implementation as:

```
typedef struct vector {
   int size;
   char buffer[];
} vector;
vector* create_vector( int size ) {
   vector* p = (vector*) malloc( sizeof *p + size ); // manually allocate "size" extra
   p->size = size;
};
int main() {
   vector* v = create_vector(10);
   for ( int i = 0; i < v->size; ++i )
      printf("%d\n", v->buffer[i] );
   free(v);
}
```

But the language does not allow you to initialize with the curly braces as the compiler does not know how much memory has to be held (in general, in some circumstances it can know). The size-less member of the struct is only a way of accessing beyond the end of the object, it does not hold memory in itself:

```
printf( "sizeof(vector)=%d\n", sizeof(vector) ); // == sizeof(int)
```

Comment: I would strongly rather not say it is used as a pointer, lest beginners get tripped up with arrays vs pointers again.  Even though the member name ("buffer" above) is used to refer to the memory following the object, this isn't the same type of pointing that pointers do.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: I agree that it could cause confusion if read as *the array is a pointer*, so I have reworded, even if what really happens at this stage is exactly that: the array is used as a pointer (the only uses of that member are those that require the array to decay into a pointer)

Answer (score 0):

In C++03, this is not allowed in struct or class!

## Comeau C++ compiler gives this error:

> ```
> "ComeauTest.c", line 3: error:  
> incomplete type is not allowed 
>       char arr[ ];
>            ^
> ```

Exactly simlar question yesterday : [Difference between int* and int[] in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851234/difference-between-int-and-int-in-c/4851326#4851326)